# A comparison between some structures of the verbs 'Supply' and the verb 'provide'

Tags: verb-usage

For me both the verbs "Supply" and "provide" work in all of the sentences bellow properly, but I doubt if AE native speakers use all of them to convey the same meaning in daily conversations. Though, I need to know which one of the following structures are used more in AmE in order to convey thees meanings?

**Question 1)**

A) I have no job!
B) Really?! Then...

> - How do you **supply** your expenses?
> - How do you **provide for** your expenses?

**Question 2)**

> - In order to **provide** water **for** the city the government has made new decisions.
> - In order to **supply** water **to** the city the government has made new decisions.
> - In order to **supply** the city **with** water the government has made new decisions.

Comment: Hard to tell from those what the actual questions are intended to convey. Can't answer without better context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither answer in question 1 has the right tone for what you're trying to say. You don't supply or provide anything to expenses, your food and rent bills supply *you* with expenses and you *pay* them.

> 1) How do you pay your expenses?

All answers in question 2 have almost exactly the same meaning. The only difference is the verb *to supply* sounds a little more long term, like you're providing the city with water on more than one occasion.

If I **provide** a city with water then I've probably delivered a lot of water bottles, but if I **supply** a city with water then I've built water pumps and reservoirs. Be aware that you can still use *supply* for a short-term solution and *provide* for a long-term solution, but the verb *supply* tends to be used for long-term solutions more often.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Just please tell me about "furnish"? What about the sentence:   ( - In order to furnish the city with water the government has made new decisions. )  does that mean the same like the above-mentioned sentences?

Comment: "Furnish" can't be used for things that can be consumed or things that travel around, it can only be used for things that can be described as furniture. I can furnish a city with streetlights or statues, but I can't furnish a city with vehicles or food.

Comment: Thank you again. And as my last question in this respect, could you please tell me weather these three sentences mean exactly the same or not: ( " - In order to provide water for the city the government has made new decisions. " )  AND ( " - In order to provide the city with water, the government has made new decisions. ) AND ( " - In order to provide water to the city, the government has made new decisions. )

Comment: Absolutely no difference at all!

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. Your posts were really helpful.